# Run time error 424 in VBA for only one user

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I have a macro that is run each week by various users and one user randomly gets a run time error when trying to run the macro.

I haven't been able to recreate it as the macro runs fine on my computer and all other users.  The file template is saved on a network and copied each week for whichever user needs it.

The windows version they are running is that same as other users and no other changes are made to the file that would cause any errors.

My IT Dept has looked into it and there's no issue on that end from a hardware or connectivity problem.

The error occurs as soon as the button linked to the macro is pressed and does not provide a debug line.

Any ideas why one user would get this error?

```
Public Sub CrtReport()

    RptAbort = False
    RptProcess = True
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    UserForm1.Show
    If RptAbort Then Exit Sub
    

    Sheet11.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheet1.Select

    Call ClearSubtotals
    Call ClearReportRetail
    
    ans = BldReport()
    If ans = False Then
        xyz = MsgBox("No data for the selected department", vbCritical, "Markdown Tool")
        Sheet3.Select
        Exit Sub
    End If
    Call BldClassTotals

    Sheet1.Copy Before:=Sheet6
    
    Dim Answer$
    Answer = Application.InputBox("Enter new sheet name")
    If Answer = "" Then Answer = "xyz"
    
    Sheet3.Select
    Range("B14") = Answer

    
    Sheet12.Select
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row
    Cells(lastRow + 1, 9) = Answer
    
    Sheets("Retail Template (2)").Select
    Sheets("Retail Template (2)").Name = "Retail " & Answer


    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$AY$50000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="S"

    Range("E14").Select
    Sheet1.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    

    Sheet14.Visible = xlSheetVisible
    Sheet14.Select

    Call ClearSubtotals
    Call ClearReportRetail
    
    Call BldReportE
    Call BldClassTotalsE

    Sheet14.Copy Before:=Sheet6
    
    Sheets("ECOMM Template (2)").Select
    Sheets("ECOMM Template (2)").Name = "ECOMM " & Answer


    Columns("AD:AI").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Template", Replacement:=Answer, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A10").Select
    

    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$9:$AY$50000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="S"
    

    Sheet14.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    
    Sheets("Retail " & Answer).Select


    Columns("AD:AE").Select
    Selection.Replace What:="Template", Replacement:=Answer, LookAt:=xlPart, _
    SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, _
    ReplaceFormat:=False
    Range("A10").Select
        

    Call UpdateEcommLRD
    Call UpdateRetailLRD

    

    Sheet5.Select
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then


        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AY$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Sheet12.Range("b1").Value
    Else
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter


        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AY$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Sheet12.Range("b1").Value
    End If


    Range("$A$2:$AY$50000").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Range("A1").Select
    
    Sheet6.Select
     lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
    If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then


        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AY$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Sheet12.Range("b1").Value
    Else
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.AutoFilter


        ActiveSheet.Range("$A$2:$AY$50000").AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="<>" & Sheet12.Range("b1").Value
    End If


    Range("$A$2:$AY$50000").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    Selection.Clear
    Range("A1").Select
    

    Sheets("Retail " & Answer).Select

    Range("A10").Select
    
    RptProcess = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: It is impossible to diagnose code you haven't shared. Please create a [reprex].

Comment: Please share the specific code that is raising this error.

Comment: If using `Workbooks(workBookNameHere)` be sure to include the file extension.

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. Please also include details about the error.